Hay alternativas al uso de Store Procedures (Procedimientos almacenados)?
Trabajo con Javascript puro en el front-end y con NodeJS + MySQL en el back-end.
Cuando debo realizar procesamientos medianamente complejos con los datos de las tablas, los hago dentro de Procedimientos Almacenados en MySQL lo cuál me resulta engorroso. ¿Hay alguna alternativa a los Procedimientos Almacenados para realizar los procesamientos de datos a los que me refiero?

Gracias al aporte recibido en esta misma página, respondo la duda: los procesos a los que me refiero en la pregunta, pueden ser resueltos sin hacer uso de Procedimientos Almacenados. Las alternativas son: querys y ORM. Cada alternativa tiene sus ventajas y desventajas.

Estoy seguro de que a alguien le servirá, como me sirvieron a mi las que recibí.
